# Presenting multiple choice question results in Google Data Studio

Tags: charts, looker-studio

I want to use Google Data Studio to present the results of a form, in which I have a multiple choice question. Let's say we have option1, option2, and option3, and the respondents can choose any number of these: the result column will contain the responses separated by commas, e.g. "option1, option3".

I would like to present that as a bar chart in Google Data Studio, but can't find how.

If I set the field as "dimension", the chart has the correct labels for the bars, i.e. "option1", "option2" and "option3", but I can't find what to put as metrics to present in each one, how many times that has been responded.

I've tried breaking them out as separate boolean columns, in which case I can compute the count of each answer, but don't know how to put them in the same bar chart...

I expect to see a bar chart with labels "option1", "option2", "option3", and the count of each one as the height of each bar.

Comment: Have you tried using the same dimension in the metrics section with aggregation set as count (should do it automatically)?

Comment: Yes, but it counts only the answers containing only one option. If I have option1, option2 and option3, and someone checked all of them, the answer will be "option1, option2, option3" and data studio does not count it in either bin.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do separate calculated metrics for each option

Metric for option 1 example would be

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(YourDimension, "(?i).*Option 1.*")THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
```

Repeat for each option and then add to your graph individually